# How can I get an object from a json script in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, drupal

I need to use the 'options' object that's in this json script [image]

is there a way to extract it using jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: `console.log(Drupal.settings)`

Answer (score 0):

Get the innerText of the script tag and then parse the JSON.

```
var options = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('script[data-drupal-selector="drupal-settings-json"]').innerText);
```

Comment: While this does work, according to the HTML5 spec this is a misuse of script tags.

Comment: My answer didn't misuse the script tag so your comment is irrelevant. Drupal is a huge and well trusted platform, I'm sure they're know what they're doing.